# Problem with real device and socket.io in Flutter

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

i have this issue when i tried to run my app in a physical device in debug mode.
When I try to debug the next code:

```
class SocketService with ChangeNotifier {
  ServerStatus _serverStatus = ServerStatus.Connecting;
  SocketService() {
    this._initConfig();
  }
  void _initConfig() async {
    IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://192.168.56.1:3000/', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });

    socket.on('connect', (_) {
      print('connect');
    });
    socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
    socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
    socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
  }
}
```

And in my backend i have this:

file *index.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('./sockets/socket');

const publicPath = path.resolve( __dirname, 'public' );
app.use( express.static( publicPath ) );

server.listen( process.env.PORT, ( err ) => {

    if ( err ) throw new Error(err);
    console.log('Servidor corriendo en puerto', process.env.PORT );

});
```

file *socket.js*

```
const { io } = require('../index');

io.on('connection', client => {
    console.log('Cliente conectado');
    client.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Cliente desconectado');
    });
    client.on('mensaje', ( payload ) => {
        console.log('Mensaje', payload);
        io.emit( 'mensaje', { admin: 'Nuevo mensaje' } );
    });
});
```

In web works good and print's the 'disconnect' adn the 'connect' perfectly, but when i tried to debug in my cellphone, nothings happends, i don't get any message from the socket instance, if anyone knows how to solved this I would appreciate.

Comment: its because most probably your phone does not have access to the server on that port. do you have port 3000 open for access on your server?

Comment: @naif.mazen I'm a begginer in this, so, i don´t know how to do that, if you can to tell me more details i would appreciate a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what was the problem, was with the *AndroidManifest*
The way I solved was with the next code

In the `<application>` I add this line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

The result was this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.band_names">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="band_names"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your code into the [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-architecture) server or you can make a [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/product/ngrok-link) URL to connect the socket with a physical device.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me to figure out the issue. The issue was with the AndroidManifest.xml 

Inside the `<application>` I have to put this line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and that works.